# Resources Not Found Exception

Tags: android, exception, android-arrayadapter, logcat, android-resources

Hi i am getting a Resourcesnotfoundexception in my adapter code..

Code:

```
   public class Bag_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> implements Filterable {
   //in getview()  
        {
         try {
                    int i = getContext().getResources()
                            .getIdentifier(name().toLowerCase(), "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
                Log.wtf("Called", "Drawable=" + i);

                    holder.icon.setImageResource(i);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.wtf("Called", "Error=" + e);
                }
        }
```

Here is error logcat:

```
08-20 19:58:24.732 12650-12650/com.bot.pokego A/Called: Drawable=android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200bf
08-20 19:58:24.786 12650-12650/com.bot.pokego A/Called: Drawable=2130837716
```

I tried cleaning,deleted build folders also........but still same error.

I am using Android Studio .

Any help will be appreciated !.

Thanks ! inadvance :).

Comment: `name().toLowerCase()` is not the name of an existing drawable.

Comment: @Rotwang name() function returns the name of a object ...than i convert it to lowercase to match to the name of image in my drawable-v21 folder

Comment: I understand what it does. But it doesn't return what you are expecting it to.

Comment: @Rotwang So how can i do it ?

Comment: Try `.getIdentifier("my_drawable_name"` instead. Check out why `name()` doesn't work properly

Comment: Thanks it worked :)...plz add it as answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: ... what could I add as an answer? you answered yourself, with a little guidance by my side. Next time, [ask the Rubber Duck](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your resources folder. If you keep your resources in higher version folder v21 and test on lower version you may get this exception.

Hope it helps !!!